# How can one calculate "probability of possessing a ‘perfect’ profile" from "typical optimal genotype frequencies"?

Tags: population-genetics, genomics

Can anyone please explain how the "Probability of possessing a ‘perfect’ profile" was calculated from "typical frequency of optimal genotype" in Table 1 in this paper?

Paper link [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2375556/pdf/tjp0586-0113.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

They appear to have simply considered each allele independently. This means that if there are say 2 alleles for a trait, and they are both present at a frequency of 0.1 in the population, then you have a 0.01 chance of having both of them. This is probably an okay assumption for their purposes (in reality some might be linked and would associate non independently). Their point is simply that as the number of alleles go up, having all the best ones becomes increasingly unlikely.

Comment: Makes sense, but still I am not able to figure out the math here. Can you please be kind enough to take an example from this table and explain how the probability was calculated?

Comment: seems like i cracked it .. thank you so much for the explanation